# Rails 4 - Polymorphic associations & paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I am making an app in rails 4.

I have 3 models: user, profile and address.

The associations are:

user.rb

```
has_one :profile
```

profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
```

address.rb

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

In my address views folder, I have a partial, called _location.html.erb, which has:

```
<span class="sideinfo">
    <% if @country_name.present? %>
        <%= @country_name %> 
    <% else %>
        <span class="profileeditlink">
            <%= link_to "Add your location", edit_address_path %>
        </span>
    <% end %>       
</span>
```

In my profile show page, I render the location partial:

```
<%= render 'addresses/location' %>
```

In my address model, I have a method for:

```
 def country_name
    self.country = ISO3166::Country[country]
    country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name
  end
```

In my address form, I have an input field for the country:

```
                <%= f.input :country, priority: [ "Australia", "New Zealand", "United Kingdom" ] %>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to create an edit location path which lets the user update its location (country_name) from the profile show page.

I have tried the format set out in my location partial above. When I do that, I get this error:

```
Couldn't find Address with 'id'=1
```

That's because I haven't yet made an address for my test profile (I think).

Is there a way I can create a new address if I click the edit link (like find or create by)? How would I set that up?

Comment: if you are adding an address, try `new_address_path` helper instead of `edit_address_path`

Comment: But if there is already an address, it should be edit. Is there a way you can adjust the helper based on whether an address exists?

Comment: sure, just check for `user.addresses.empty?` and if true use the `new_` helper, if false, use the `edit_` helper.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *edit* an existing address, you need to pass the `id` of the object you wish to edit:

```
<%= link_to "Add your location", edit_address_path(address) %>
```

--

The corresponding routes and controller should look like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :addresses #-> url.com/addreses/:id/edit
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user

   def edit
      @address = @user.addresses.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @address = @user.addresses.find params[:id]
      @address.update
   end

   private

   def set_user
      @user = current_user #-> assuming you're using Devise
   end
end
```

I think you're getting confused with `nested routes` but I'd need to see the routes to be sure.

Comment: Hi Rich. Thanks for this. I'm not sure why you think I have nested routes. Address isn't nested in my routes.